# Swift: Exception while trying to print CLLocationSpeed "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make a super simple program that will as of right now print the speed from the iPhone's gps. This is my code so far:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  GpsSpeed
//
//  Created by Jacob Sandum on 4/18/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Jacob Sandum. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import CoreLocation
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    locationManager.delegate = self
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .NotDetermined {
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
  var speed: CLLocationSpeed = CLLocationSpeed()
    speed = locationManager.location.speed
    println(speed);
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

When I try to run this code I get this fatal exception: `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)`

I think CLLocationSpeed is nil, but I do not know how to fix this.

Comment: Do you know which line the execution stops on?

Comment: The execution stops on "speed = locationManager.location.speed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` in to your info.plist file

Then the full code is

```
 import UIKit
import CoreLocation
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        locationManager.delegate = self
        if NSString(string:UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion).doubleValue > 8 {
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    }
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        var speed: CLLocationSpeed = CLLocationSpeed()
        speed = locationManager.location.speed
        println(speed);
    }
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status != CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied{
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
}
```

Run it on **real Device**

Your error:

1. Do not get speed in `ViewDidLoad` it will only be called once.So,in your code, every time you try to get location before it start updating.
2. It is better to get speed when location update
3. It is better to start updating when auth changed

Comment: @Leo The speed freeze at the last location update. But when the object is at a standstill, then enter values in the last saved speed last update location. How to fix it? Thank you!