# What I am doing wrong with my CLLocation?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am trying to make a simple app that shows:
Latitude
Longitude
Horizontal Accuracy
Altitude
Vertical Accuracy
Location From Start

My code is:

```
@IBOutlet weak var latitude: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var longitude: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var horizontalAccuracy: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var altitude: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var verticalAccuracy: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var distance: UILabel!

var locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
var startLocation: CLLocation!

@IBAction func resetDistance(sender: AnyObject) {
    startLocation = nil
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
    didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!)
{
    var latestLocation: AnyObject = locations[locations.count - 1]

    latitude.text = String(format: "%.4f",
        latestLocation.coordinate.latitude)
    longitude.text = String(format: "%.4f",
        latestLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    horizontalAccuracy.text = String(format: "%.4f",
        latestLocation.horizontalAccuracy)
    altitude.text = String(format: "%.4f",
        latestLocation.altitude)
    verticalAccuracy.text = String(format: "%.4f",
        latestLocation.verticalAccuracy)


    if startLocation == nil {
        startLocation = latestLocation as! CLLocation
    }

    var distanceBetween: CLLocationDistance =
    latestLocation.distanceFromLocation(startLocation)

    distance.text = String(format: "%.2f", distanceBetween)
} 


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
    didFailWithError error: NSError!) {

}
```

And then in the ViewDidLoad section:

```
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    startLocation = nil
```

I keep getting the error: on the latitude.text line (everything hooked up correctly)

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

(lldb)

How would I go about adding **if let** statements? Can you help me find the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Swift. You can't do anything with an AnyObject. Cast down like this:

```
    let latestLocation = locations.last as! CLLocation
```

Also, you say "everything hooked up correctly", but I'm not sure I believe that; try doing `println(latitude)` to make sure.

Finally, this code is not going to work:

```
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

The problem is that the authorization request is *asynchronous*. Thus you possibly are starting to update locations before you've actually got authorization. You have to wait until you actually *have* authorization before you start asking for updates.

Comment: Thanks so much. I have two questions. One, it where should I put the let latestLocation. It says use of unresolved identifier. Secondly, how do I get authorization? Thanks so much!

Comment: It might help you to look at working code: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch22p773location/ch35p1032location/ViewController.swift

Answer (score 2):

**About how to get authorizaiton:**

First add **NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription** in to your info.plist file

Then in viewDidload:

```
if NSString(string:UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion).doubleValue > 8 {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
```

Then is this delegate method,start updateingLoation

```
 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status != CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied{
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
```

Then when you get location,you can convert it to `CLLocation` as **matt** post

You may also refer to this link about details, this is an answer I answered before
[Swift: Exception while trying to print CLLocationSpeed "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090102/swift-exception-while-trying-to-print-cllocationspeed-unexpectedly-found-nil-w/30090420#30090420)